# tmux - how to enter Ctrl + Backslash?

Tags: tmux

Sometimes after starting a terminal process I need to use `Ctrl` + `\` to stop it.  Sometimes I can use `Ctrl` + `C` but sometimes this is not sufficient and therefore `Ctrl` + `\` is necessary.

How can I enter `Ctrl` + `\` from within tmux?  If I press `Ctrl` + `\` that seems to be a tmux shortcut key that takes me to a special tmux screen like this:

[image]

rather than sending `Ctrl` + `\` to stdout for the current tmux pane.

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and here is my tmux version:

```
tmux/focal-updates,now 3.0a-2ubuntu0.3 amd64 [installed]
```

I'm `ssh`ing into an AWS EC2 instance if that matters.  Here is my `~/.tmux.conf`, perhaps I need to make a change here but I'm not sure what to change:

```
# Change prefix to <Ctrl+a>
unbind C-b
set -g prefix C-b

# Force tmux to send <Ctrl+a> signal to program if you do `<Ctrl+a> a`,
# so I can still go to start of line
bind a send-prefix

# Set default shell
set-option -g default-shell /bin/bash

# UTF is great, let us use that
#set -g utf8
#set-window-option -g utf8 on

#Allows 256 colors in tmux
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# 0 is too far from ` 
# set -g base-index 1
# setw -g pane-base-index 1

# don't rename windows automatically
set-option -g allow-rename off

set -g status-keys vi
set -g history-limit 10000

setw -g mode-keys vi
setw -g monitor-activity on

# quickly switch between sessions with prefix+q
bind-key q choose-tree

# Split panes vertically and horizontally
bind-key v split-window -h
bind-key s split-window -v

bind-key J resize-pane -D 5
bind-key K resize-pane -U 5
bind-key H resize-pane -L 5
bind-key L resize-pane -R 5

bind-key M-j resize-pane -D
bind-key M-k resize-pane -U
bind-key M-h resize-pane -L
bind-key M-l resize-pane -R

# Vim style pane selection
bind h select-pane -L
bind j select-pane -D
bind k select-pane -U
bind l select-pane -R

# smart pane switching with awareness of vim splits
bind -n C-h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"
bind -n C-j run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-j) || tmux select-pane -D"
bind -n C-k run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-k) || tmux select-pane -U"
bind -n C-l run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-l) || tmux select-pane -R"
bind -n C-\ run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys 'C-\\') || tmux select-pane -l"

# Use Alt-vim keys without prefix key to switch panes.
# M stands for the Meta key in iTerm.
# -n stands for window-name
bind -n M-h select-pane -L
bind -n M-j select-pane -D
bind -n M-k select-pane -U
bind -n M-l select-pane -R

# Use Alt-arrow keys without prefix key to switch panes
bind -n M-Left select-pane -L
bind -n M-Right select-pane -R
bind -n M-Up select-pane -U
bind -n M-Down select-pane -D

# Shift arrow to switch windows
bind -n S-Left  previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window

# No delay for escape key press
set -sg escape-time 0

#  Reload tmux config
bind r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display "Reloaded!"

######################
### DESIGN CHANGES ###
######################

# panes
set -g pane-border-fg black
set -g pane-active-border-fg brightred

# messaging
set -g message-fg black
set -g message-bg yellow
set -g message-command-fg blue
set -g message-command-bg black

#window mode
setw -g mode-bg colour6
setw -g mode-fg colour0

# window status
setw -g window-status-format " #F#I:#W#F "
setw -g window-status-current-format " #F#I:#W#F "
setw -g window-status-format "#[fg=magenta]#[bg=black] #I #[bg=cyan]#[fg=colour8] #W "
setw -g window-status-current-format "#[bg=brightmagenta]#[fg=colour8] #I #[fg=colour8]#[bg=colour14] W "
setw -g window-status-current-bg colour0
setw -g window-status-current-fg colour11
setw -g window-status-current-attr dim
setw -g window-status-bg green
setw -g window-status-fg black
setw -g window-status-attr reverse

# Info on left (I don't have a session display for now)
set -g status-left ''

# loud or quiet?
set-option -g visual-activity off
set-option -g visual-bell off
set-option -g visual-silence off
set-window-option -g monitor-activity off
set-option -g bell-action none

set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"

# The modes {
setw -g clock-mode-colour colour135
setw -g mode-attr bold
setw -g mode-fg colour196
setw -g mode-bg colour238

# }
# The panes {

set -g pane-border-bg colour235
set -g pane-border-fg colour238
set -g pane-active-border-bg colour236
set -g pane-active-border-fg colour51

# }
# The statusbar {

# status line
set -g status-justify left
set -g status-interval 2
set -g status-bg colour234
set -g status-fg colour137
set -g status-attr dim
set -g status-left ''
set -g status-right ' #S #[fg=colour233,bg=colour243,bold] %a %b %d, %Y #[fg=colour233,bg=colour245,bold] %-I:%M %p '
set -g status-right-length 50
set -g status-left-length 20

setw -g window-status-current-fg colour81
setw -g window-status-current-bg colour238
setw -g window-status-current-attr bold
setw -g window-status-current-format ' #I#[fg=colour250]:#[fg=colour255]#W#[fg=colour50]#F '

setw -g window-status-fg colour138
setw -g window-status-bg colour235
setw -g window-status-attr none
setw -g window-status-format ' #I#[fg=colour237]:#[fg=colour250]#W#[fg=colour244]#F '

setw -g window-status-bell-attr bold
setw -g window-status-bell-fg colour255
setw -g window-status-bell-bg colour1

# }
# The messages {

set -g message-attr bold
set -g message-fg colour232
set -g message-bg colour166

# }

# Rearrange windows (move current window Ctrl + Shift + Direction[arrow key])
bind-key -n C-S-Left swap-window -t -1
bind-key -n C-S-Right swap-window -t +1

# Enable mouse control (clickable windows, panes, resizable panes)
set -g mouse on
```

--- Edit ---

Response to questions from K. Maciorowski in the comments section:

1. The `.tmux.conf` I've posted above is from the EC2 instance.
2. I'm entering a tmux session only after `ssh`ing into the EC2 instance, i.e. I'm not using tmux on my local machine.
3. On the EC2 instance, in the `/etc` directory, there is no file named `tmux.conf` or `.tmux.conf`.  The only tmux config file seems to be the one posted above, which is at `~/.tmux.conf`

--- Edit2 --

Additional response to questions from K. Maciorowski in the comments section:

1. Yes, the problem happens when I start a new tmux session.
2. $ tmux list-keys -T root | grep -F 'C-'
   bind-key -T root C-\              run-shell "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys 'C-\') || tmux select-pane -l"
3. If I do:

   tmux unbind-key -T root 'C-'

before entering a tmux session then that does solve the problem, Ctrl + \ then does what it normally would.

Based on this I commented out the line

```
bind -n C-\ run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys 'C-\\') || tmux select-pane -l"
```

in `~/.tmux.conf` then rebooted and that seems to have solved the problem, if you post your diagnostics steps as an answer I will accept.

Comment: When `ssh`ing, one may use `tmux` locally or on the remote side (or in both places). Please confirm the `.tmux.conf` you posted is from the machine your `tmux` runs and you don't use `tmux` on the other machine. Does `/etc/tmux.conf` exist on the relevant machine? What is the content?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski posted additional clarification as you've instructed in the post

Comment: Does the problem appear when you start a tmux server anew? What is the output of `tmux list-keys -T root | grep -F 'C-\'`? Does `tmux unbind-key -T root 'C-\'` help at least temporarily?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski posted additional info per you're further questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `~/.tmux.conf` commenting out the line:

```
bind -n C-\ run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys 'C-\\') || tmux select-pane -l"
```

then killing the tmux session and starting a new one (or rebooting) makes `Ctrl` + `\` work as expected within tmux